# Inconsistent behavior of SVN Info with externals

Tags: svn, svn-externals

Due to a complex structure in a SVN repository, some external files are not correctly retrieved from the repository.  As changing the repository structure is not an option, I have developed a script that iterates through the externals and retrieves them 'by hand' if needed (thanks to 'svn export').  To detect if this operation is indeed needed, I execute 'svn info', assuming that it will return different from 0 if the file does not exist, or it is not versioned.  That was indeed the behavior obtained in host1 (SVN Client 1.6.17):

```
# Initially, the directory is empty
host1$ ls
host1$ svn update

Fetching external item into 'main.rbf'
svn: warning: '<REMOTE_SVN_LOCATION1>'
is not the same repository as
'<REMOTE_SVN_LOCATION2>'

At revision 18413.

# Although we do the update, the external item is not fetched,
# as it is a single file coming from a different repository
# (known problem)
host1$ ls
# The file is not present, and SVN info acts accordingly
host1$ svn info main.rbf
main.rbf:  (Not a versioned resource)

svn: A problem occurred; see other errors for details

# If we force the SVN export
host1$ svn export <REMOTE_SVN_LOCATION1> main.rbf
A    main.rbf
Export complete.
host1$ ls
main.rbf

# then SVN info detects it and acts accordingly
host1$ svn info main.rbf
main.rbf:  (Not a versioned resource)

svn: A problem occurred; see other errors for details
host1$
```

In host2, (SVN Client 1.6.11), the behaviour of 'SVN info' is completely different: no matter if the file is there (from a previous export) or not, the answer is:

```
# Directory is empty
host2$ ls
host2$ svn info main.rbf
Path: .
URL: <REMOTE_LOCATION>
Repository Root: ...
Repository UUID: ...
Revision: 18413
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: ...
Last Changed Rev: 18326
Last Changed Date: ...

host2$
```

Is there any reason to explain this inconsistent behavior? How can I detect this unversioned file in host2 ?

Comment: Why you don't want to fix broken externals?

Comment: Not in my hands to do that...

Comment: You can do it without changes in repo-tree: `svn:external` *parent dir *of files to *some path* in TARGET-REPO, modify file-externals to use files from the same repo

Answer (score 0):

`svn info` and `svn info FILENAME` do **different** things.

Second form can get info about *unversioned file*, first form get info about *current dir* inside WC

Comment: Of course.  If you e see the example, you'll notice that I am always using the second form.

Comment: @Marda - second form will never work for **unversioned resource**, and I see `host2$ svn info`

Comment: Exactly, that's what I expect, that's the information I use in my script and that's the behavior I get in host1.
Why do I get a different behavior in host2 ? (I have corrected the posted code)

Comment: Well, 1.6.11 behavior is definitely wrong, why not update this ancient version?